# Run Spring Boot App as service

Tags: spring, unix, spring-boot

I want to run my Spring Boot app as service i create this script on `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Unit]
Description=Application_Test
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=jenkins
ExecStart=java -jar /var/myapp/app.war
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run this command:

```
systemctl enable myapp.service
```

I do a start

```
service start myapp
```

I have this error:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  myapp.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit myapp.service failed to load: Invalid argument.
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to inquire the way to the JDK in my script

```
[Unit]
    Description=Application_Test
    After=syslog.target

    [Service]
    User=jenkins
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /var/myapp/app.war
    SuccessExitStatus=143

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```